# ORACLE DB Connects only when I do not specify SID

Tags: oracle-19c

I have an Oracle 19c database in a Unix server.
SQLPLUS command connects only when I do not specify the SID.

```
sqlplus system/manager
SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Mon Jul 20 12:37:30 2020
Version 19.3.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Last Successful login time: Mon Jul 20 2020 11:45:41 +05:30

Connected to:
Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.3.0.0.0

SQL>
```

However, when I try with the SID, it does not connect.

```
sqlplus system/manager@S19110

SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Mon Jul 20 12:40:01 2020
Version 19.3.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

ERROR:
ORA-12537: TNS:connection closed


Enter user-name:
```

I see the following in my listener.log :

```
TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
TNS-00517: Lost contact
Linux Error: 32: Broken pipe
```

I googled the error and tried the following troubleshooting methods but no help.

1. 6751 permission for $ORACLE_HOME/bin/oracle
2. Increase max number of processes in the database.

Please help.

Comment: Have you tried doing tnsping S19110? Does it get resolved?

Comment: Yes. tnsping gets resolved.

Comment: When I try connecting from SQL Developer, I get the below error :
`io error got minus one from a read call.`

And listener.log has the same error that I mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. But I don't have any explanation why or how it worked.
It worked after removing `GLOBAL_DBNAME` parameter in `listener.ora` under `SID_LIST_LISTENER`